# I am getting this error while displying a pdf file using react-pdf and also it is not loading the pdf file because of this

Tags: reactjs

notes:1 Refused to execute script from 'http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.worker.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

I have tried some solutions that are given on google but none of them solved the error everything is working properly while I am trying to show the pdf using react-pdf

Comment: Can you provide more detailed errors and also solutions that you have tried with your code snippet or reproducible example?